# Grub installation failed with fresh installation 14.04 on VMware ESX 5.1

Tags: grub2, 14.04, esx

I'm trying to install server 14.04 on VMware ESX 5.1 and received grub installation failed error

```
grub-pc package failed to install into /target/
```

I used normal BIOS, not EFI. Tried only installing OpenSSH service did not help. Tried with and without LVM when creating partition.

How can we resolve this issue?

Comment: Your VMware is old. Try updating to *VMware ESX 5.5 Update 1*

Comment: I had the same problem with 16.04. Even tried installing on a regular machine and not a VM. Got the same error. I went back and disabled the network connection on the VM and tried the install and VOILA, it worked. So the problem still exist on the newer version also I guess. Just wanted to let others know it works for them too.
Scott

Answer (score 3):

After trying many different options, I remember 12.04 also had the same problem and solution was remove Network Adapter from VM setting then install ubuntu without network card.
I tried the same with 14.04 and voila grub install successfully. After boot up, we just need to add Network adapter again then we are done.
I thought I need to share this as many people will have the same issue.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted(click on the check mark besides the answer) since it has worked for you. And yes, this seems to be a workaround than a solution.

Comment: I did not need to completely remove the network adapter, but just uncheck "Connect" and "Connect on startup".

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately all I can add is conjecture, but I had this issue and got past it.

I believe this might have some correlation with vmware provisioning and your ram to hard drive ratio.

Even though in theory I had enough disk space, and ubuntu did not warn about space restraints like it normally would, I believe because it was a close ratio this caused grub to fail.

Grub installs after almost every other package.

In my case I had 1gb ram, 2gb volume.  Failed every time at install grub, even with network adapter disable and removed.

Tried again today this time with 3gb volume, and installed fine.

Good luck!